# Maven change local respository after Window update

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

My project using Java and Maven. My .m2 is in directory C:\Users\my_user_name. I use this .m2 directory as unique repository of my project .Everything worked Ok before. I have also built my project success on yesterday. Today, my window 7 update and when i build my project, I get the error

> Failed to collect dependencies for [org.jboss.solder:solder-impl:jar:3.1.0.Final (compile), or
>   g.jboss.solder:solder-api:jar:3.1.0.Final (compile), org.jboss.solder:solder-logging:jar:3.1.0.Final (compile), log4j:lo
>   g4j:jar:1.2.6 (provided), javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:1.0-SP4 (provided)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jboss.solder:solder-impl:jar:3.1.0.Final: Failure to find org.jboss.seam:seam-bom:pom:3.1.0.Final in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

I have debug the problem with command `mvn -X` and I get the result

> Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 20:51:28+0700)
>   Maven home: D:\soft\maven\apache-maven-3.0.5
>   Java version: 1.7.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
>   Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre
>   Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
>   OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
>   [INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
>   [DEBUG] Reading global settings from D:\soft\maven\apache-maven-3.0.5\conf\settings.xml
>   [DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.m2\settings.xml
>   [DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.m2\repository
>   [DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10 for C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.m2\r
>   epository

As you see, the maven use a repository `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile` . I have checked and see an another .m2 directoty in there, and this .m2 directory have not enough .jar file.

I also put  `<repositories>` config tag with content

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>repo.maven.apache.org</id>          
          <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>repository.jboss.org</id>          
          <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>maven.nuxeo.org</id>          
          <url>https://maven.nuxeo.org/nexus/content/repositories/public</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>   
      </repositories>
```

in file settings.xml in 
`C:\Users\my_user_name\.m2\repository`.So my question is :How to change local repository to .m2 in `C:\Users\my_user_name` ? (because this .m2 is right repository and i have put all my .jar to this repository ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay close attention to the error message you are getting:

> Failure to find org.jboss.seam:seam-bom:pom:3.1.0.Final in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, **resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced**

So Maven is telling you that it won't attempt to fix the dependency problem until you tell it to force updates.  Here is how you do that:

```
mvn clean install -U
```

or

```
mvn clean install --update-snapshots
```

The `-U` flag does the following (from typing `mvn -help`):

> Forces a check for missing releases and updated snapshots on remote repositories

Comment: @TungVo Was this answer helpful for your problem?